# How to replace image src based on screen size in Java Script

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, image-replacement

I am changing my background image with the help of Java Script and I have both desktop version image and mobile version image.

When the screen size is reduced to below 600px, I want my desktop version images should be replaced with mobile version images.

Can someone help me on this and below is the code snippet.

```
const hbg = document.querySelector('.hbg');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');

hbg.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.querySelector('.nav').parentNode.classList.add('active');
})

closeBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    document.querySelector('.nav').parentNode.classList.remove('active');
})

const data = [
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-1.jpg",
        header: "Discover innovative ways to decorate",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-2.jpg",
        header: "We are available all across the globe",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-3.jpg",
        header: "Manufactured with the best materials",
    }
]

let currentPage = 0;

const slide = () => {
    const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
    const next = document.querySelector('.next');
    const page = document.querySelector('.main-page');
    const header = document.querySelector('.header');

    const updateContent = () => {
        page.style.backgroundImage = `url(${data[currentPage].image})`;
        header.innerHTML = data[currentPage].header;
    }

    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentPage++;
        if(currentPage > data.length-1){
            currentPage = 0;
        }
        updateContent();
    })

    prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentPage--;
        if(currentPage < 0 ){
            currentPage = data.length - 1;
        }
        updateContent();
    })
};

slide();
```

Comment: you can use `media query` css for different size of device

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Are you looking to change the image src with JS ?

Comment: You could also have a look at the HTML5 `<picture>` Tag. There you be able to add sources for different screen-sizes:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

You'll find more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_picture.asp

It's still well supported at "up-to-date" browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=picture

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object structure like this.

```
const data = {
    'desktop' : [
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-1.jpg",
        header: "Discover innovative ways to decorate",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-2.jpg",
        header: "We are available all across the globe",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-3.jpg",
        header: "Manufactured with the best materials",
    }],
'tablet' : [
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-1.jpg",
        header: "Discover innovative ways to decorate",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-2.jpg",
        header: "We are available all across the globe",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-3.jpg",
        header: "Manufactured with the best materials",
    }],
'mobile' : [
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-1.jpg",
        header: "Discover innovative ways to decorate",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-2.jpg",
        header: "We are available all across the globe",
    },
    {
        image: "images/desktop-image-hero-3.jpg",
        header: "Manufactured with the best materials",
    }]
}
```

The event you want to be looking for is 'onresize'. Check for your conditions and assign  the images again.

If you do not want to handle resize, you can simply

```
 const updateContent = () => {
if(window.innerWidth <360){

}
else if(window.innerWidth <786){


}
else if()

....
    }
```

But I would suggest using media queries and adding your images from there, unless you want an only JS based solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping Tushar. I am just trying to do things differently for learning purpose.

Comment: Sure. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it works for you.